# Listado con salto de línea cuando hay overflow horizontal

Tags: css, css3

La cosa es que tengo un listado muy extenso, que además es a base de imágenes (no se si esto complica el asunto). Además quiero que el listado sea en horizontal.

La cosa sería que yo no quiero que haya *overflow* horizontal, quiero que en ese momento haga un salto de línea y así sucesivamente hasta el final de la lista.
La pregunta es esa, ¿cómo hago para que haga ese salto de línea?

(En el caso que no se pueda detectando el ancho de la pantalla, ¿cómo se haría estableciendo un ancho fijo?).

No puedo adjuntar código, puesto que el problema es que no sé cómo afrontarlo. En HTML simplemente hice un listado donde cada `li` contiene una imagen:

```
<ul>
  <li><img src="imagen1.jpg" />
  <li><img src="imagen2.jpg" />
  <li><img src="imagen3.jpg" />
  ...
  <li><img src="imagenM.jpg" />
</ul>
```

Y el CSS no sé cómo hacerlo, se me ocurre que al contenedor de la lista hacerle un `display:flex;` pero ni idea de cómo afrontar eso.

Comment: Hola Carlos si no puedes afrontar el problema significa que solo buscas opiniones? Revisa [ask]

Comment: Si no sabes cómo afrontar el código, al menos tendrás una idea de cómo quieres que se vea. Deberías añadir una imagen o algo más descriptivo con el resultado que tienes ahora y el que quieres obtener. Así como el código que tengas ahora, que aunque no esté muy avanzado, puede servir a otros usuarios para entender mejor el problema y basar su respuesta en el mismo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa los sgte:

```
Padre{
    display:flex; 
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

te recomiendo que investigues e indages acerca de flexbox y como usar cada unas de sus propiedades para el diseño responsive

Comment: Okay, si es cierto

Answer (score -1):

Podrías usar la propiedad `float:left`, entonces se irán anidando una al lado de la otra

```
li {float:left }
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar, pero el problema no es conseguir la lista horizontal, sino que se haga el salto de línea.

Comment: Disculpa gnm3000, no es exactamente lo que yo quería pero si hace algo que se acerca. MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS.

Comment: Hola. Gracias por la respuesta. Podrias mirar [answer] para hacer tu proxima respuesta mas atractiva? Bienvenido!

Comment: @CarlosMilles con esta solución el salto de línea ocurriría automáticamente (el primer elemento que no entre en la línea saltará a la siguiente). Debes explicar mejor cómo es exactamente lo que quieres y cómo esta solución se acerca (pero no es).